# VBA Copy Worksheet from Unopened Workbook to Active Workbook FASTEST WAY

Tags: vba, excel

I am writing a macro that on a button click in the destination workbook, copies information from a worksheet in an unopened workbook to a worksheet in the current workbook. I've tried copying the data from the source worksheet to the destination worksheet and I've also tried copying the entire source worksheet and pasting it into the destination workbook. Both methods have proven to be extremely slow as the documents I'm using are quite large and the source file needs to be opened each time.

What I am looking for is a method that doesn't open the source workbook (if that's even possible), or any advice as to how I could speed up the process.

I am trying to learn VBA so a pseudo code solution is welcome!!

Comment: http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=454

Comment: You can query a closed workbook with ADO. I would recommend that as it will be much faster than the `ExecuteExcel4Macro` solution. I have used both.

Comment: Without opening the file, you will only be able to retrieve the *values* from the sheet, none of the formatting, shapes, charts, etc.

Comment: The same goes for `ExecuteExcel4Macro` about formatting, shapes, etc, correct @DavidZemens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below will give you a recordset `rst` that contains the data from `Sheet1` of the workbook you use in your connection string. You didn't provide much in the way of specifics, so either ask follow up questions, or adjust this code as necessary.

It's important to keep in mind that the connection string *may* change if you use a different format Excel workbook (ie .xls, .xlsm).

EDIT:
This now outputs the whole recordset on Sheet1 of whichever workbook you set to `wbk` (starting in cell A2) and puts the column headers in row 1.

This also requires a reference to a Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects library.

```
Sub ExampleOfADO()

Dim conn as New ADODB.Connection
Dim rst as New ADODB.Recordset
Dim wbk as Workbook
Dim i as Long

Set wbk = yourworkbook

With conn
    .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
    .ConnectionString = "Data Source=C:\Desktop\File.xlsx;Extended Properties = 'Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR =YES'"
    .Open
End With

rst.Open "Select * FROM [Sheet1$]", conn

With wbk.Sheets(1)
   .Range("a2").CopyFromRecordSet rst

   For i = 0 To rst.Fields.Count - 1
      .Range("a1").Offset(0, i) = rst.Fields(i).Name
   Next i
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: IMO your answer is incomplete without description of how to output field names and recodset data to worksheet (e. g. using recordset `.GetRows` method).

Comment: @omegastripes, valid point. This is updated to input the data and column headers. I prefer the method above, but another, different, answer is not only welcome, it is preferable.

Comment: For the above code to work, a reference to Microsoft ActiveX Data Object library must be added.

Comment: I get the following an error: "Runtime -2147467259 (80004005) Cannot update. Database or object is read only." Its happening at With conn .Open. Any leads on an error like this?